# How to create a sql update script instead of executing the update statements with Flyway

Tags: flyway

Is it possible to instruct command line Flyway to write down the needed SQL update commands in a file, instead of executing them in the Database?

Comment: Since you create the scripts for flyway to run, you have them in a file(s) already, don't you?

Comment: @rbfish: the point is, that flyway select the right scripts (the one that are not executed yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported yet. Please +1 https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/87